# Failing to route to a desired action and not passing the Custom Segment Variable

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework-4, asp.net-mvc-routing

I have these two routes. The second one passes  an  optional custom variable to an action method and directs it to an action called DatedPosts.

```
    routes.MapRoute(
        name: "Default",
        url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
        defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
    );


    routes.MapRoute(
    name: "GetDatePosts",
    url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
    defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "DatedPosts",  id = UrlParameter.Optional}
    );
```

My action method gets the parameter if it is defined and turns into a date then it gets all the posts from a blog. That is, if there are any on that date which I pass onto the view. This method does what I want it to do:

```
        public ActionResult DatedPosts(string id)
        {
            //Post post = new Post();

            m_requestedDatedPosts = true;
            Session["RequestDatedPosts"] = m_requestedDatedPosts;

            string date = null;

            char oldChar = '/';
            char newChar = '-';
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(id))
            {
                date = id.ToString();
            }

            //will hold the formated date
            string formatedDate = null;


            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(date))
            {
                //Convert dateString to shortDateString by replacing slashes with dashes
                formatedDate = date.Replace(oldChar, newChar);
            }
            else
            {
                ViewBag.CustomVariable = id == null ? "no posts with that date" : id;
                return RedirectToAction("Error", "Posts");
            }

            //put all posts in a list
            List<Post> m_posts = (from post in db.Posts select post).ToList();

            List<Post> m_datedPosts = new List<Post>();

            //var posts = (from post in db.Posts where post.CreatedDate == DateTime.Parse(formatedDate) select post).ToList();

            //Traverse the list of posts and get those with the given date
            foreach (var post in m_posts)
            {
                if (post.CreatedDate.ToShortDateString() == formatedDate)
                {
                    m_datedPosts.Add(post);
                }
            }

            //If there are no posts with that date redirect to Error action on post controller
            if (m_datedPosts.Count() == 0)
            {
                return RedirectToAction("Error", "Posts");
            }

            Session["DatedPostList"] = m_datedPosts.ToList();

            return RedirectToAction("Index", "Posts");
        }

This is my action View :

@{

    List<Post> posts;


    if (Session["RequestDatedPosts"] == null)
    {

        string requestDatedPostsStr = Session["RequestDatedPosts"].ToString();

        requestDatedPosts = Convert.ToBoolean(requestDatedPostsStr);

    }


    var datedPostList = (List<Post>)Session["DatedPostList"];

      if (requestDatedPosts)
    {

        posts = datedPostList;
    }

}

foreach (var post in posts)
{


    <div class="newsResult">

        <div class="title">@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => post.Title)</div>

        <div class="updated"> <b>Created:</b> @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => post.CreatedDate) </div>

        <div class="updated"> <b>Updated:</b> @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => post.UpdateDate)</div>

        <div class="data"> <b></b>  @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => post.Body)</div>

}
```

The result is that the routing works, if and only if, I define the date in the route beforehand like this and if only have this route:

```
    routes.MapRoute(
    name: "GetDatePosts",
    url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
    defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "DatedPosts", id = "2014/05/21" }
    );
```

This, however, is not what I want. In the browser I want to type the date of my choice like this Localhost/DatedPosts/2014/05/21/ and get the posts at that day if there are any.

All I get is a HTTP Error 404.0 - Not Found. In addition, while testing I found out another thing that I want to avoid. It turns out that the way my routing works is that I have to write a link LocalHost/DatedPosts/DatedPosts/  in order to ,at least, be redirected to the error page. Again, this is not what I want, I want a link like this:  Localhost/DatedPost/2014/05/22 and to get all posts at that date.

Can anybody help?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The routes you have listed are essentially the same thing, the URL portion is identical so the routing engine has no way of differentiating between the requests.

To get what you are after try the following:

```
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "GetDatePosts",
    url: "DatedPost/{*id}",
    defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "DatedPosts",  id = UrlParameter.Optional}
);

// default route should (generally) be last to ensure it doesn't catch any requests that may look similar 
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "Default",
    url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
    defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
);
```

Comment: Thanx Brent!!! I Think it worked... I have a question, in the first route there is defined  url: "PostsAt/{*id}", Is this the same as  url: "PostsAt/{*catchall}"? Why only two segments if there are three at least?

Comment: Yes and no, the `*` donates the catch all, while the `id` portion of URL maps to the `string id` parameter on the action. If the parameter on the action was `string date` for example, the URL could be defined as `PostsAt/{*date}`. If we hadn't used the catch all, the date portion would have to be defined as `PostsAt/{year}/{month}/{day}` which would mean your action would have `string year, string month, string day` as parameters.